# Pandas - convert dataframe multi-index to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

Consider an input file, `b.dat`:

```
string,date,number
a string,2/5/11 9:16am,1.0
a string,3/5/11 10:44pm,2.0
a string,4/22/11 12:07pm,3.0
a string,4/22/11 12:10pm,4.0
a string,4/29/11 11:59am,1.0
a string,5/2/11 1:41pm,2.0
a string,5/2/11 2:02pm,3.0
a string,5/2/11 2:56pm,4.0
a string,5/2/11 3:00pm,5.0
a string,5/2/14 3:02pm,6.0
a string,5/2/14 3:18pm,7.0
```

I can group monthly totals like so:

```
b=pd.read_csv('b.dat')
b['date']=pd.to_datetime(b['date'],format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
b.index=b['date']
bg=pd.groupby(b,by=[b.index.year,b.index.month])
bgs=bg.sum()
```

The index of the grouped totals looks like:

```
bgs

            number
2011 2       1
     3       2
     4       8
     5      14
2014 5      13

bgs.index

MultiIndex(levels=[[2011, 2014], [2, 3, 4, 5]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]])
```

I'd like to reformat the index into date time format (days can be first of month).

I've tried the following:

```
bgs.index = pd.to_datetime(bgs.index)
```

and

```
bgs.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(bgs.index)
```

Both fail. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I get an error if I use this code directly with Pandas 0.13. It breaks on the `pd.to_datetime` call, claiming that the use of `%p` is incorrect via `KeyError: 'p'` in `/pandas/tslib.so in pandas.tslib.array_strptime (pandas/tslib.c:20989)`.

Comment: In fact, I can reproduce the pandas error with any string needing to parse the 'am' or 'pm'. There must be a bug in handling how that gets passed to `strftime` or whatever.

Comment: Opened a [pandas issue here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7381).

Comment: @EMS for info I'm on version 0.13.1 (it works for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by 'M' rather than grouping by attributes of the DatetimeIndex:

```
In [11]: b.resample('M', how='sum').dropna()
Out[11]:
            number
date
2011-02-28       1
2011-03-31       2
2011-04-30       8
2011-05-31      14
2014-05-31      13
```

Note: you have to drop the NaN if you don't want the months in between.

Comment: That's great thanks - I'm trying to find more info on the 'rule' parameter. How do you know that 'M' groups by month. I'd like to know what else can it do. There's possibly a search term I don't know in order to find it in the man pages?

Comment: The keyword is "offset" http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases :)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a column from the index via the date calculation you want, then set that as the index:

```
bgs['expanded_date'] = bgs.index.map(lambda x: datetime.date(x.year, x.month, 1))
bgs.set_index('expanded_date')
```