# Create Datetime index after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to revert index after `groupby` function.

Question is how to create a DateTime index having year, month, day in separate columns in Multindex.

Given a `DataFrame` as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-1-31 23:50:00', freq='10min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B'],index=index)
```

Then, get the sum over each hour using `grupby`:

```
day_h = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.day,lambda x: x.hour]).mean()
```

This creates an Index, where year, month, day and hour are in separate columns.

```
                      A         B
2011    1   1   0    0.209908  1.196164
2011    1   1   1    0.692531  0.518185
2011    1   1   2    1.674748  0.013136
2011    1   1   3    1.674748  0.013136 
2011    1   1   4    1.674748  0.013136
2011    1   1   5    1.674748  0.013136
```

The desired output would be to have DateTime index:

```
                 A         B
2011-1-1 00:00  0.209908  1.196164
2011-1-1 01:00  0.692531  0.518185
2011-1-1 03:00  1.674748  0.013136
2011-1-1 04:00  1.674748  0.013136
2011-1-1 05:00  1.674748  0.013136
```

In my files there are some missing rows, so I can't create a new index with 1h timestep.

My data after groupby [Example data](http://dpaste.com/1X2HNW5)

Comment: What's wrong with the current df? The index shows the relative level values, as you have multiple hours for a given day the output is correct

Comment: Also what are you trying to achieve here? Your groupby object is no different from your sample df as the mean here is the same

Comment: Yes it is correct, but I would like to get rid off Multindex and have Datetime index.

Comment: Are you really after `df.resample('h', how='mean')`?

Comment: @EdChum this would work if there are no missing values (hours, days). `resample` creates empty rows that I wouldn't like to have.  I know I can drop them but I'm looking for a solution that will take date from multiple  columns.

Comment: Your question bears no relation to your sample df, if you want to create a datetime using existing columns then you should be able to do `df.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.day,lambda x: x.hour), axis=1)` and assign this to your index

Comment: @EdChum I got fallowing error `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'year'", 'occurred at index (2011, 1, 1, 0)')'`

Comment: Can you post what your **real** df actually looks like

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: does `df.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour), axis=1)` give you what you want? This will create a datetime dtype series, you can then assign this directly to your index

Comment: This gives me an error `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'year'", 'occurred at index (2015, 4, 11, 10)')`

Comment: Sorry do you already a datetimeindex? I'm very confused by what you're asking here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89387/discussion-between-michal-and-edchum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else on SO had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090710/pandas-convert-dataframe-multi-index-to-datetime-object), but their solution was to use resample.  You can avoid resampling by mapping the tuples in the multi-index to create a new index.  This will handle missing rows just fine.

```
day_h['new_index'] = day_h.index.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
day_h.set_index('new_index')
```

Output:

```
                        A          B
new_index                                
2011-01-01 00:00:00  -1.095114   1.995776
2011-01-01 01:00:00  -2.411459   4.508794
2011-01-01 02:00:00  -1.261747   4.953709
2011-01-01 03:00:00  -0.311934   5.454112
2011-01-01 04:00:00   2.095718   6.854375
2011-01-01 05:00:00   1.696756   3.518919
2011-01-01 06:00:00   0.623589   1.740478
2011-01-01 07:00:00   0.544426   0.916016
2011-01-01 08:00:00   2.331326   0.891177
```

Comment: The only thing I was missing with @Edchum answer were magic `x[0]` and so on...Thank you @thecircus !